# Should TextureRegions in an atlas be power of 2?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

It is my understanding that images should be power of 2 for optimization with the GPU. However, if I'm packing my textures into a sheet for libGDX, can the atlas be a power of 2 and NOT the actual regions? Or should the atlas sheet be a power of 2 and each Texture Region also be a power of 2.

Comment: No, it doesnt matter which size the regions are, it is only the size of the texture that matters whether it is POT or not.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that it's not. As far as I know the reason for the need of POT (power of two) textures is for optimizations things like mipmapping, anisotropic filtering, etc. So when you pack many images in one texture then you upload that entire texture to the GPU, so the GPU can perform the desired optimizations for all the texture. The atlas is like an index to lookup for certain sectors (or "pieces") of your texture (texture regions), so you can retrieve the desired regions easily. Those regions don't need to be POW, because the GPU already perform optimizations for the entire set (the entire texture). I think that you should ask these type of questions in the [game dev community](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com), so you will have a deeper response.